# Copy to clip board from WebView

Tags: c#, webview, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

In an UWP App with a WebView control the user can:

1. Select some text from the loaded html
2. Right-click
3. Choose "Copy"

However, choosing "Copy" does not copy the text?

What is missing? Some code to handle the "copy event", or...?

Answer (score 3):

This is a **known issue** we have logged, I'm not sure the specific build version, but the fix should be available in future release.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answer, so you can copy selected content to the clipboard. So this is the code:

```
DataPackage dataPackage = await YourWebView.CaptureSelectedContentToDataPackageAsync();
Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
```