# Copy & Paste from webview content works only with keyboard shortcuts (not with mouse or touch)

Tags: webview

recognized some strange behaviour in the webview. When I load a website (for example: microsoft.com) into the webview is it possible as expected to select text on the website via mouse or touch. 
However, when I want to copy this selected text to the clipboard, this is only possible by using the keybord shortcut (Ctrl + C). If you want to use mouse (right click on the selected text + clicking copy in the appearing dropdown menu) or touch (long press on the selected text + clicking copy in the appearing dropdown menu) nothing is happening and the clipboard will not receive any new content. 
Does anyone if there is setting in the webview class which has to be enabled, to allow copy & paste also with mouse and touch? Or is that failure in the webview? Is there a workaround? Or do I just miss anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy to clip board from WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479593/copy-to-clip-board-from-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue we have logged, I'm not sure the specific build version, but the fix should be available in future release